# Multivariate t approach multivariate normal

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution

It is well known that in univariate case, as we increase the degree of freedom in a t distribution, it will limit to normal distribution. Does the result hold true for the multivariate case as well?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the proof is the same. You need need to show that the limit as the degrees of freedom go to $\infty$, the expression involving the variable converges to an exponential.